# Configure cmake file for compiling on Linux for Windows

Tags: c++, linux, windows, gcc, clion

I'm using clion IDE on my Debian Linux for c++ coding and recently I got stuck in configuring CMakeLists.txt for compiling program for Windows. Can anyone show an example of CMakeLists.txt for compiling for Windows under Linux?